# 2 ListView Nested ListView

Tags: android, listview, scroll

let say i have ListView A and ListView B

the ListView B is the First item in the ListView A

in the getview Method of the listView A the addapter of the listview B will be created if a Global Value is not null

and this is working fine

what i want is to hide the first item of the list view A until its scrolls to up

if its scrolls to up then  the first item will be visible

i tried this way its working but its not having a good look

what i really want is to make the user feels like he is scrolling to up not refreshing the list

the getView of ListView A

```
    if (position == 0) {


            if (!GlobalConstants.relatedHashs
                    .isEmpty()) {
                if (GlobalConstants.relatedHashs
                        .size() > 0) {

                    String str = PublicMethods
                            .readable(media.getDescription_());
                    Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("#(\\w+|\\W+)");
                    Matcher mat = MY_PATTERN.matcher(str);

                    while (mat.find()) {
                        // System.out.println(mat.group(1));ArrayList.
                    GlobalConstants.relatedHashs
                                .add(0, "#" + mat.group(1));
                    }

                    Set setItems = new LinkedHashSet(
                            GlobalConstants.relatedHashs);
                    GlobalConstants.relatedHashs
                            .clear();
                GlobalConstants.relatedHashs
                            .addAll(setItems);

                    holder.IncludeCommentLinearLayout
                            .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.IncludeMediaFragmentLinearLayout
                            .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.TopHash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.ActiveLin.setBackgroundColor(GlobalConstants.color9);

                    holder.ActiveTopics.setText("Related Topics");
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            context,
                            R.layout.hash_items,
                            R.id.textItem,
                            GlobalConstants.relatedHashs);

                    // Assign adapter to ListView
                    holder.listHash.setAdapter(adapter);

                holder.listHash
                .setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        int action = event.getAction();
                        switch (action) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            // Disallow ScrollView to intercept
                            // touch events.
                            v.getParent()
                                    .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(
                                            true);
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch
                            // events.
                            v.getParent()
                                    .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(
                                            false);
                            break;
                        }

                        // Handle ListView touch events.
                        v.onTouchEvent(event);
                        return true;
                    }
                });


            }
```

and in the activity

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        x1 = event.getX();
        y1 = event.getY();
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        x2 = event.getX();
        y2 = event.getY();

        // if left to right sweep event on screen
        if (x1 < x2) {
            Log.e("left to right", "left to right");
        }

        // if right to left sweep event on screen
        if (x1 > x2) {
            Log.e("right to left", "right to left");

        }

        // if UP to Down sweep event on screen
        if (y1 < y2) {
            Log.e("UP to Down", "UP to Down");


                if (getin) {

                    Parcelable state = listview.onSaveInstanceState();
                GlobalConstants.relatedHashs = relatedHashs1;

                    MediaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listview.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
                    getin = false;

            }

        }

        // if Down to UP sweep event on screen
        if (y1 > y2) {
            Log.e("Down to UP", "Down to UP");
        }
        break;
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```

you must know that the Listview A is dynamic list that at least have tow items

this is working good but its so annoying 
i need this to be like its  smooth scrolling not a refrishing

Comment: A ListView in a ListView... sounds like an ExpandableListView, to me.

Comment: No its Not ExpandableView

Comment: The point is: `why don't you use an ExpandableListView` for that? It sounds like a better idea.